# Shindig + OAuth + Persistance

Tags: widget, opensocial, apache-shindig

I have read a good dozen of articles (including ones from stockoverflow), slides and tried samples from the Apache. I'm a back-end Java developer, still struggling with client side part.

My task is simply a build To-Do widget and be able to store data created "Tasks" in db. Could anyone share some good example how to do this? In seems server-side REST works, nevertheless I don't know how to connect this a widget so that is doesn't persist data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does Shindig fit into the picture?  Are you trying to build an OpenSocial To-Do gadget?

Comment: Shindig server is used for REST. I'm using ToDo gadget from labpixies (http://www.labpixies.com/campaigns/todo/todo.xml). My goal is to be able to login using Google Oauth and, then, to store todos in db for the current user. It is a preliminary goal so that I can make the same with other gadgets.